# Macro isn't Looping Through Workbooks As Expected

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro that inserts formulas into columns B-F in all worksheets in a workbook. For some reason the workbook loop isn't working and the macro just continuously runs in the first workbook. Anyone have any ideas?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Formuoli()
Dim iLastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
    iLastRow = Range("a10000").End(xlUp).Row
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        For i = 1 To iLastRow
            Range("B" & i).Select
            Selection.Formula = 'these are formulas
            Range("C" & i).Select
            Selection.Formula = 'these are formulas
            Range("D" & i).Select
            Selection.Formula = 'these are formulas
            Range("E" & i).Select
            Selection.Formula = 'these are formulas
            Range("F" & i).Select
            Selection.Formula = 'these are formulas
        Next i
    End With
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing the dots before `.Range(....`. For example (after the for i = 1 to iLastRow) it should be `.Range("B" & i).Select`. Yet, it would be even better to use `.Range("B" & i).Formula = 'these are formulas`.

Comment: Also, I highly **highly** recommend reading through [How to avoid using `.Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). In short, you can delete any `.Select` text and back up the `Selection.` put to where `Select` was...so you could do `.Range("B" & i).Formula = ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a few dots before the `Range` functions:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Formuoli()

Dim iLastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        iLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To iLastRow
            .Range("B" & i).Formula = "" 'these are formulas
            .Range("C" & i).Formula = "" 'these are formulas
            .Range("D" & i).Formula = "" 'these are formulas
            .Range("E" & i).Formula = "" 'these are formulas
            .Range("F" & i).Formula = "" 'these are formulas
        Next i
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

Changes:

1. Added the required dots.
2. Moved `iLastRow` into the loop to determine the last row for each sheet.
3. Combined several rows by removing the `Select`.

Comment: Thank you! this is very helpful